# How to call a script and return the set variable value to a dockerfile?

Tags: python, bash, docker, return

I have a `dockerfile` that calls a `bash shell` which executes a command to fetch the `IP address` and stores it into a variable. How do I return the variable's value from a bash shell to a dockerfile? After the variable is returned in the `dockerfile`, how do I access that variable in a `python` file?

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.0-wheezy
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y

WORKDIR /usr/src/mongodb

COPY . /usr/src/mongodb

## What I've tried ##
#CMD ['./script.sh']
#RUN bash 'export ip=`awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts`'
ENV ip="bash 'export ip=`awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts`'"

EXPOSE 27017
```

---

hello.py (boilerplate code):

```
mongoIP = os.environ.get('ip')
print(mongoIP)
```

Comment: what is in the shell script? If you are trying to just bind ip why not just have a setup shell script before all this?

Comment: The shell script only contains "export ip=`awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts`". So I decided to make it a one liner rather than running a whole file for the one line.

Comment: How do you create a setup shell script?

Comment: That's not possible, a Dockerfile describes how to build an immutable image. Dynamic run time values can't be set there.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve? There is probably another way to do it, usually this sort of thing happens in an ENTRYPOINT script.